# WebGrid column header initial sort direction

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've got a webgrid that shows a report of amounts and my customer wants that when the user clicks on the headers the initial sort direction should be descending, how can i achieve this?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: The only thing i've found is how to reverse the sorting if no sort direction is set, specifing in the view this statement:
    `code`if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request[webGrid.SortDirectionFieldName]))
    {
        webGrid.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
    }`code` but it's useless

Comment: How come it's useless? It's the same approach I would suggest if you haven't mentioned it.

Comment: The above piece of code sorts the model passed to the webgrid with the default sort field descending if no sort direction is set, instead my grid needs to be sorted with the clicked header's sort field and descending in first instance, then alternate the sort direction if re-clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution:
Since my grid has got an arrow symbol on the clicked header that displays the sort direction, in the callback function that renders my grid's partial view i collect with jQuery all the header links that haven't got any sort symbol in their text and i replace "sortdir=ASC" with "sortdir=DESC" in the links' querystring, keeping the eventual clicked sort column sort state and letting the other ones start the sorting descendingly, like this:

```
var $sortingLikns = $grid.find("thead a[data-swhglnk=true]");
$sortingLikns.each(function (idx, elem) {
    if ($(elem).text().indexOf("▴") === -1 || $(elem).text().indexOf("▾") === -1) {
        $(elem).attr("href", $(elem).attr("href").replace("sortdir=ASC", "sortdir=DESC"));
    }
});
```